# Correct? Proof that $f:[a,b]\rightarrow \mathbb R$ continuous $\Rightarrow$ uniformly continuous.

Tags: real-analysis, solution-verification, uniform-continuity

Is this acceptable proof of continuous $f:[a,b]\rightarrow \mathbb R$ being uniform continuity? Pick some $\epsilon \in \mathbb R_+$, now for all $x\in[a,b]$ there exists a $\delta_{x,\epsilon}$, such that $|f(x)-f(x+h)|<\epsilon$, when $h<|\delta_{x,\epsilon}|$.

Define now a sequence $x_n=\inf \{x:\delta_{x,\epsilon}<\frac{1}{n}\}$. This is an increasing sequence by construction and bounded by $b$. We have

$$\sup_n x_n=\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty} x_n=x_\infty \in [a,b].$$

Now
$$|f(x_\infty)-f(x_\infty+h)|<\epsilon, \space \space \space 0\leq |h|<\delta_{x_\infty,\epsilon}$$

Hence we have $0<\delta_{x_\infty,\epsilon}$. Conclude by noting that $f$ is continuous so the same applies in the neighborhood, hence for all $x$ we have $\delta_{x_\infty,\epsilon}\leq\delta_{x,\epsilon}$ and hence we can choose $\delta_{\epsilon}=\delta_{x_\infty,\epsilon}$.

Comment: This doesn't look right. Intuitively, your enemy is not _$\delta$ getting too large_ but rather _$\delta$ getting to close to zero_. And the reasoning has a number of flaws, but I suspect the intuitive mistake is more important.

Comment: @MichałMiśkiewicz Thanks, good observation. Now fixed... (the first part).

Comment: @Dole I am not sure I follow the second part. What is allowing you to conclude that $\delta_{\infty,\epsilon}\leq \delta_{x,\epsilon}$ for any x?

Comment: @AndrewMcMillan It's the $x$ where the inf of $\delta$ occurs in the neighborhood + a small constant (which is missing indeed). Perhaps it would be easier to just write $\inf\{\delta_{x,\epsilon}\}$, and pick the $x_\infty$ associated with $\delta_{x,\epsilon}$.